# Ext JS: Template with period in dataIndex

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm trying to create an XTemplate, and one of my dataIndexes has a period... so my data looks something like this:

```
{
  "one": 1,
  "two.one": 21,
  "two.two": 22
}
```

Now, when I'm creating the template, I can't do something like **{two.one}** because that thinks **two** is the beginning of an object, and then I'm accessing its key **one**. I've tried doing something like **{'two.one'}**, but this also doesn't work, and I've tracked it down to the culprit in [Ext.XTemplateCompiler.parseTag](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/XTemplateCompiler.html#Ext-XTemplateCompiler-method-parseTag).  This code is what breaks it:

```
// compound Javascript property name (e.g., "foo.bar")
else if (isNaN(name) && name.indexOf('-') == -1 && name.indexOf('.') != -1) {
  v = "values." + name;
}
// number or a '-' in it or a single word (maybe a keyword): use array notation
// (http://jsperf.com/string-property-access/4)
else {    
  v = "values['" + name + "']";
}
```

So with my **two.one** string, I get into that else if, but what I really want is the else that follows right after it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can override this in an easy way... does anybody have any thoughts? I'm using Ext JS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to skirtle over on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289201-Template-with-period-in-dataIndex.&p=1056449&viewfull=1#post1056449), I was able to solve it:

Instead of using **{two.one}** or **{'two.one'}**, it should be **{[values['two.one']]}**.  Using values directly was the ticket.

Comment: Why don't you change `.` to `_` for example?

Comment: Because the `.` actually implies that it's a collapsed object... if you create a store with nested hash data, say `{one: 1, two: {one: 1}}`, you can set the dataIndex of that field as `two.one`, and it will auto-collapse the nested hash data into `'one': 1, 'two.one': 1`.

Comment: And I realize I can use [`mapping`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-mapping), but my use case is different.

Comment: You can use `two['one']` instead.

Comment: That's not how it works when it's created in the model... I've got it working the way I need it.  Thanks for the suggestion.